# Angular.js - $scope.variable doesn't auto update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var chatModule;

  chatModule = angular.module('chatModule', ['diplomovaPraceFrontendApp']);

  chatModule.service('chatModuleService', function(UserService, socket) {
    var obj,
      _this = this;
    obj = {};
    obj.chats = [];
    obj.initiate = function(from) {
      if (!_.has(obj.chats, from)) {
        return obj.chats[from] = {
          messages: []
        };
      }
    };
    obj.logIncoming = function(data) {
      return obj.chats[data.from].messages.push({
        text: data.message,
        type: 'in'
      });
    };
    obj.send = function(chat) {
      return socket.emit('private-message', {
        to: chat.profile_hash,
        from: UserService.profile_hash,
        message: chat.message
      });
    };
    socket.on('private-message', function(data) {
      return obj.logIncoming(data);
    });
    return obj;
  });

  chatModule.directive('chat', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/ChatModule/chatModule.html'
    };
  });

  chatModule.controller('ChatCtrl', function($scope, chatModuleService) {
    $scope.send = function(chat) {
      return chatModuleService.send(chat);
    };
    return $scope.chats = chatModuleService.chats;
  });

}).call(this);
```

If I am not mistaken, when changing the service's value, being assigned to the `$scope`, it should automatically update the `$scope`'s variable and therefore update corresponding the HTML. But this doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Now it looks better :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, the problem was:

```
obj.chats = [];
```

is supposed to be:

```
obj.chats = {};
```

The best is console didn't give me any errors or a clue.